# Internet explorer - SID S-1-5-5-0-348885

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer

While running in the protected mode, I noticed the Internet Explorer has permission for internet SID S-1-5-5-0-348885. Which user this SID maps to?

Comment: Hi Rockr. I notice that you've asked 9 questions, but never accepted an answer or cast a vote. It's considered polite to give an upvote and the checkmark to the answer that has helped you the most, otherwise people may be hesitant to assist in the future if they know they will receive no reward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330), that SID is for Logon Session, and is unique for each session. The last two values are not static.